# convert cavtivedataprovider to array with specific form

Tags: php, arrays, yii, merge

im using yii1 on my application.
i want to convert from cActivedataProvider to array

this is the code

```
    $dataSS = new CActiveDataProvider('category', array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'condition' => 'menu=:menu',
            'params' => array(':menu' => $menu),
        ),
        'pagination' => false
    ));
   $dataMenu = array();
   foreach ($dataSS->getData() as $record) {
      $dataMenu[] = array(
              'label' => $record->name,
               'url' => '#',
       );
   }
```

this is the result :

```
 Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [label] => Food and Drink [url] => # ) 
[1] => Array ( [label] => Sleman [url] => # ) 
)
```

the result that i expected :

```
Array ( 
    Array ( 'label' => 'Food and Drink', 'url' => '#' ) ,
    Array ( 'label' => 'Sleman', 'url' => '#' ) ,
    )
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between what you are getting and what you expected?

Comment: the result that i get cant used as menu form on yii1

Comment: @PieterHaro There are no difference between that two arrays. Please provide your CMenuWidget code.

Comment: Hi @TaronSaribekyan this is my code on [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/Nrc99q4G)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get the answer,
this is really my bad because i call the function on wrong way.

---

This is the wrong way :

```
'items' =>array(Category::model()->getMenu("2");),
```

and this is the correct way :

```
'items' =>Category::model()->getMenu("2"),
```